# Why Are Some WPF Custom Style Elements Ignored Whilst Others Adhered?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I'm a bit confused trying to understand how style overrides inside the visual tree work.

I've got two examples - the first, defining `DataGridCell` works perfectly, as shown.

The second, defining `ToggleButton`, is completely ignored, but I'm hard pushed to find out why the first one works, but the second does not. Can anyone offer any insight?

### Working - `DataGridCell` Style Defined in `DataGrid.Resources`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding hello}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"><!--DataGridCell is a child of DataGrid's Visual Tree -->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border Padding="10" Background="Red">
                          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

[image: working]

---

### Non-Working - `ToggleButton` Style defined in `Resources` is ignored:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"><!--ToggleButton is a child of Expander's Visual Tree-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>Hello World!</TextBlock>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Resources>
    <Expander.Header>Header</Expander.Header>
    <Expander.Content>Body</Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

[image]

Comment: This is because some controls define their own styles for controls they use. You should have a look at the default styles (of Expander for example). You can do that in Blend by selecting the control, right click, edit style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some controls define their own `Styles` for the controls they use. For example the default template for `Expander` defines a `ControlTemplate` for `ToggleButton` and sets it like this (I dont want to copy the whole default style in here because its quite long):

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" 
    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" 
    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ... Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" ... />

<Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Because this is a local value, it takes precedence over your style that is defined as a resource.
As dkozl mentioned in the comments, check [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#listing) to find out which takes precedence over what.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like `ToggleButton` in this case is taking 4th precedence (from that list) and is ignoring my 5th precedence?

Comment: `ToggleButton` sets the style as a local value (`Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}"`), so it is 3rd precedence.

Comment: And you are correct, the style you define is 5th precedence, which is overwritten by the local value